# How to apply rate-based throttling in Google Cloud Armor for a specific URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, throttling, rate-limiting, pulumi, google-cloud-armor

I want to apply rate-based throttling using Google Cloud Armor. In the configuration for rules, there is a `match` parameter but that is for matching the IP ranges. I could not find a way to filter and then apply rate-based throttling for specific URL endpoints.

Via Pulumi documentation, I was able to find that we can leverage [`enforceOnKey` for the `HTTP_PATH`](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/securitypolicy/#enforce_on_key_python) but it takes only the first 128 bytes of the request.

I wonder if there are some examples I can use to apply rate-based throttling for specific URLs. Such as 1k QPS for `/login`, 10k QPS for `/insert`.

From the logs, I think the `httpRequest.requestUrl` parameter, can be used to enforce this rule.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand the workflow you want to setup.

You could draft a compound CEL rule like this:

> request.path.lower().matches('/login') && inIpRange(origin.ip, '9.9.9.0/24')

Where you check for the path and the IP range and then set the action to rate limit.

```
gcloud compute security-policies rules create 299 --project=[projectName] --action=throttle --security-policy=test --expression=request.path.lower\(\).matches\(\'/login\'\)\ \&\&\ inIpRange\(origin.ip,\ \'9.9.9.0/24\'\) --preview
```

You **can't** use a rule like inIpRange(origin.ip, '*') && request.path.lower().matches('/login|/insert') as the value needs to equate to TRUE in both halves of the CEL statement and there is no string match in the wildcard statement to tell if it is true.

I may be overthinking what you want to do- perhaps you can do an exact match of the path as a CEL rule and then set the rate limit (without the IP range). You would set up 2 different rules, one for each path + rate limit. The counts are maintained separately if you have 2 separate rules.

Comment: Small correction. Replace `projectName` with `projectId`.